# Arduino html auto-refresh for constant data stream

Tags: html, arduino

We're trying to have the web page served by the Arduino update without having to refresh the page. Our current code is below. Right now the page is refreshing as fast as possible (about once a second), but we'd like to have the data update without having to refresh. Is there a way to do this with html?

Thanks for your help!

```
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
  Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
  String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the     client
  while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
    if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
      char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
      Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
      if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

        // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
        // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
        if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
          // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
          // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-type:text/html");

          client.println();

          voltageReading = analogRead(A0);

          //meta-refresh page as fast as possible
          client.print("<HEAD>");
          client.print("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
          client.print("<TITLE />Smart 3 Phase Relay TCNJ</title>");
          client.print("</head>");
          // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
          client.print("Voltage Reading: ");
          client.print(voltageReading);

          // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
          client.println();
          // break out of the while loop:
          break;
        }
          else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
          currentLine = "";
        }
      }
      else if (c != '\r') {    // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
      currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
    }

    // Check to see if the client request was "GET /H" or "GET /L":
    if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the LED on
    }
    if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);                // GET /L turns the LED off
    }
  }
}
// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("client disonnected");
}
}
```

Comment: doesn't ajax do this?

Comment: how would I use AJAX with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is connectionless, that means you can't know if the data has changed. It is said that you can only "PULL", and ajax still pull, but it take xml/json data instead of all html.

But as far as i can understnd, you want a "PUSH" technology, with means the server send new data to clients when avaiable; that is possible using "WebSocket", but it need a server rewrite to support the protocol, or you can use a [library](https://github.com/brandenhall/Arduino-Websocket)
A websocket can be used like a normal socket (with some security restriction enforced by browser, principally you can only connecf to the same domain/ip of the HTML server), that means that once a connection is established, you can just print and read it like you do with a Serial!